# ¿Como se puede borrar un objeto de un array? PHP

Tags: php, array, poo, objeto

Tengo un `array` en donde guardo objetos de tipo `Materia` en las que un `Alumno`, y quiero crear una función para darse de baja de una materia, es decir, borrar un objeto del array, he probado con la función `unset()` y me dio error e investigando un poco lei que igualando la variable a `null` en `php7` haría el mismo efecto y borraría el objeto del array, pero no soy capaz de hacer el borrado del objeto. el fragmento de código que muestro es un simple trozo ya que lo más desarrollado.

```
<?php
class Materia{
    $nombre;
    public function __construct($nombre){
        $this->nombre=$nombre;
    }
}
?>
<?php 
class Alumno{
  $nombre;
  $misMaterias=array();
  public fucntion __construct($nombre){
  $this->nomre=$nombre;
  } 
  public function getMaterias(){
    return $this->misMaterias;
  }
  public function darBajaManual(Materia $pMateria){
    foreach ($this->getMaterias() as $unaMateria) {
      if($unaMateria==$pMateria){
         $unaMateria=NULL;
         return 'te has dado de baja de '.$pMateria;
      }
    }
  }
}     
?>
<?php
$mates=new Materia('matematicas');
$nuevoAlumno= new Alumno('Chris');
$nuevoAlumno->darBajaManual($mates);
var_dump($nuevoAlumno);
?>
```

Comment: Tienes algun error?

Comment: Puedes utilizar unset(array[data]); para eliminar algo dentro de tu arreglo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El asunto esta en el foreach:

```
foreach ($this->getMaterias() as $unaMateria) {
  if($unaMateria==$pMateria){
     $unaMateria=NULL;
     return 'te has dado de baja de '.$pMateria;
  }
}
```

el objeto `$unaMateria` es una copia de cada uno de los elementos de `getMaterias()`. Cuando haces `$unaMateria=NULL`, realmente no has borrado la materia del array de materias del alumno.

Para poder hacer eso, puedes cambiar el `for` añadiendo el indice `(key)` del array:

```
foreach ($this->misMaterias as $key => $unaMateria) {
  if($unaMateria==$pMateria){
     unset($this->misMaterias[$key]);
     return 'te has dado de baja de '.$pMateria;
  }
}
```